# Understanding $elemMatch with nested arrays

Tags: mongodb

I have these documents in my mongo db:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65fc67d03f5dfc5ebdea5a1f"
  },
  "test": [
    {
      "test1": [
        "a",
        "b"
      ]
    },
    {
      "test1": [
        "a",
        "d"
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

I want to use only `$elemMatch` to extract objects which contain "a" in "test1" array. Couldn't do it even after following [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) section. For instance this query is returning empty:

```
db.comments.find({
  "test": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "test1": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "$eq": "a"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: $elemMatch is not required if you are only testing 1 field and 1 criterion.  The query you show appears to work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/yvxLTzmy7f0

Comment: aH, I had two double quotes on of the elements in my db on atlaas. Yes, query is working. Would you care to explain why $elemMatch is not required if only testing 1 field and 1 criterion?

Comment: From the docs: "The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches **all** the specified query criteria." If there is only 1 criterion, there is no need to ensure a single array element matches **all** criteria.  If you a more in-depth explanation,  perhaps pose that as a separate question.